# Solidity and sensitive variables

Tags: solidity

I know that you should not write sensitive informations directly in the solidity smart contract. Like that:

```
string constant private MY_SECRET_KEY = "yiu+t|-WlOo|rx#+Ias/<?%B_Eu$[j_Uiz%ZacIC24D+&ses?Xk=$#[N05>pi`V";
```

You should never do this because everyone can show the smart contract.

My question is:

It's possible to know the content of a protected dynamic variable?
Example:

```
function setVariable(uint256 _myVar) public onlyOwner("0xA51b77306d6B3763D52F72d98F521A319E681C38") {
   myVar = _myVar;
}
```

I don't want to know how to get the value of myVar. I just want to know if it's possible to get the value of myVar (If yes, I need to find solution to secure my code).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to read onchain from a different contract. But you can read the value by querying the correct storage slot using offchain tools.

```
// Solidity
contract MyContract {
    // stored in slot 0
    uint256 protected myVar;
}
```

```
// JS
const myVar = await web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, slotNumber);
```

Docs:

- https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/internals/layout_in_storage.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage
- https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth.html#getstorageat

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for the links (I will check that)